# UserForm StartUpPosition

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a nice calendar pop up in excel and tested the UserForm position with:

`.Top = Application.Top + 125
 .Left = Application.Left + 125`

This works great however what I truly would like is to have the form pop up right next to the active cell.

What I have tried below is not working and I am not sure why.  I want the top left corner of the form to touch the top right of the active cell, however the form ends up covering the active cell

`.Top = ActiveCell.Top
 .Left = ActiveCell.Left + ActiveCell.Width`

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me as you expect:

```
    .Top = ActiveCell.Top + ActiveCell.Height / 2 + .Height
    .Left = ActiveCell.Left + ActiveCell.Width * 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Application.Version = "11.0" Then
Me.Top = Application.Top + [b7].Top + 70 - Windows(1).VisibleRange.Top
Else
Me.Top = Application.Top + [b7].Top - 4 +  (Application.CommandBars.Item("Ribbon").Height * 0.75) - Windows(1).VisibleRange.Top
End If
Me.Left = Application.Left + [b7].Left + 90 - Windows(1).VisibleRange.Left
```

is not too bad...