# Userform Positioning in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I've found quite a few tutorials on how to position userforms that you create in Excel:

- [Mr Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/459677-userform-screen-placement.html#post2347942)
- [Tom's Tutorials](http://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tutorials-for-excel-specifying-userform-position-on-screen/)
- [XTreme VB](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=324489)

And even [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081959/userform-startupposition) which uses the same method.

The problem is that Outlook appears to use different notation for it's own position - there is no such thing as:

```
Application.Left or Application.Width 
Application.Top or Application.Height
```

Does anyone know the Outlook equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook can have multiple windows - Explorers (where you see the list of messages) and inspectors (where you use the details of a single message).

Both Explorer and Inspector objects expose Width, Height, Left, Top properties. Outlook windows are exposed through

- `Application.ActiveWindow` (either Explorer or Inspector)
- `Application.ActiveExplorer`
- `Application.ActiveInspector`
- `Application.Inspectors/Explorers` collections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the explanation of why it's the case. I've now got my code working.

Comment: Great hint! You can center your form on the currently active window using `Me.Top = (Application.ActiveWindow.Top + Application.ActiveWindow.Height / 2) - (Me.Height / 2)` and `Me.Left = (Application.ActiveWindow.Left + Application.ActiveWindow.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2)`