# Fixed place and size Outlook window when opening

Tags: vba, outlook, window, size

With a VBA macro it is easy to open an msexcel or msword file with the window on a fixed place on the screen, f.i. top left corner, and a size one wants. Is the same possible with msoutlook? I do not get further then olMinimized, olMaximized and olNormalWindow.

Problem solved via this link: [Userform Positioning in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611835/userform-positioning-in-outlook/24613498#24613498) Thank you Axcel for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24613498/1911064)?

Answer (score 0):

The `Explorer` and `Inspector` classes from the Outlook object model provide the [Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.width), [Height](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.height), [Top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.top) and [Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.left) properties that can be set at runtime.